# Lateral Surface Area for Elliptical Cone.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, elliptic-integrals

How to find the lateral surface of elliptical cone?
Equation of lateral surface is

[Lateral surface equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/800ba.png)

but how to find the value of E in this equation?

Here is an example.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMj59.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.